# how to get a parent of an <span> tag containing a specific text

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I want to identify some section from an html file , each section are encapsulated in a div. To find the section, the title is usually encapsulated in a span tag.

so I have try those two solutions :

1)

```
doc_html = BeautifulSoup(doc_html, 'html.parser')
my_file['div'] = doc_html.find_all('div')
for div in my_file['div'] :
    for span in div.find_all('span'):
        if span.text == 'ABSTRACT':
            my_file['Abstract'] = div
        if span.text == 'Keywords':
            my_file['Keywords'] = div
        if span.text == 'REFERENCES':
            my_file['References'] = div
```

2)

```
for span in doc_html.find_all('span'):
    if span.string == 'ABSTRACT':
        my_file['Abstract'] = span.parent
    if span.string == 'Keywords':
        my_file['Keywords'] = span.parent
    if span.string == 'REFERENCES':
        my_file['References'] = span.parent
```

those two solutions works well for the section 'abstract' and 'keywords' but it doesn't work for the word 'references' and i don't understand because this word is also encapsulated in a span tag :

```
<span style="font-family: Times New Roman,Bold; font-size:10px">REFERENCES 
<br/></span>
```

and finally i would like to know if is a way to optimize this code like put it in one line for instance

Comment: I am a newbie here so i don't know what to do , i still have so interrogations  but i don't know if i have to make a new post or to post my question, you will find another post related to the same problem 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33084538/get-a-specific-section-from-a-html-doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just that there is a newline character after the "REFERENCES", strip it:

```
text = span.get_text(strip=True)
if text == 'ABSTRACT':
    my_file['Abstract'] = div
if text == 'Keywords':
    my_file['Keywords'] = div
if text == 'REFERENCES':
    my_file['References'] = div
```

Note that you can simplify the code and make it more pythonic by having a mapping between the texts and output dictionary keys:

```
mapping = {'ABSTRACT': 'Abstract', 'Keywords': 'Keywords', 'REFERENCES': 'References'}
for div in my_file['div'] :
    for span in div.find_all('span'):
        text = span.get_text(strip=True)

        if text in mapping:
            my_file[mapping[text]] = div
```

We can also simplify the "element locating" part of the code, but, without knowing at least the context of the problem and the desired output, it's difficult to help here.