# get a specific section from a html doc

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Hello i would like get a specific section from an html doc, this section is related to a div and is encapsulated in a span tag, the section is normally at the biginning of the document.

```
self.contents = BeautifulSoup(convert_pdf_to_html(self.path), 'html.parser')
self.keywords = self.contents.find('span',text=re.compile("(.*keywords.*|.*key-words.*)",re.IGNORECASE)).parent
```

the problem is i always have a newline character which avoid me to retrieve the related div like:

```
<span style="font-family: EICMDB+AdvTrebu-B; font-size:8px">keywords
<br/></span>
```

even with using a regular expression it doesn't work and there is no option to strip the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let me tell you that your regex is somewhat wrong, you have to escape `-` as `\-`

Anyways something similar worked for me but lately I can't combine regexes with `find`, too

```
contents = bs(open(path), 'html.parser')
keywords = contents.find(text = re.compile(ur"key\-?words",re.I|re.U)).parent
```

Comment: actually my fragment is not broken , it is just that i didn't copy paste well

Comment: OK no intention to insult, I edited my post, please add a closing ``>`` to the second span tag